# Angular-CLI does not accept cdn's in .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

How to make angular-cli understand that whenever we are adding any **CDN** (Deployed Url) of any **Styles** or **Scripts**. It should recognize that!

So far we need to add cdn's to **index.html**, as adding them to **.angular-cli.json** has no effect!

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching regarding this issue,
Rather then i found issues filed in Git in the Angular-CLI,

Someone may want to read [CDN Styles/ Scripts in .angular-cli.json configuration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6887) and also this [deploying with libraries linked to cdn in system-config.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1310) .

It clearly states they are not planning to implement this feature,
So therefore this feature itself is not present with Angular-Cli.

Hope this helps to other queries !

Answer (score 2):

the official CLI docs states:

> these(referring to styles and scripts) will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a  tag inside index.html

so why do you want to add CDN link to your `.angular-cli.json`. Adding styles and script files to the CLI config from CDN is not supported as the default behavior will fetch a local path but again no difference whatsoever in here between adding them to the `index.html` and `.angular-cli.json` as stated in the docs.

Comment: I agree @Hamed,
I am aware that after compiling it adds them to **index.html**, Still i thought it as a defect/un-expected behavior,
Also my point is that since you could add them to index.html directly, why there was flexibility given to **.angular-cli.json** to add only local path for files, when that could also be done in index.html, 
I feel this wierd !

Comment: But there's a huge problem of load order! If you need things loaded in a specific order, you can't always combine index.html stuff and angular-cli json stuff - imo it should be possible to add everything in angular-cli. systemjs is much more flexible with this btw